# Angular 4 + MVC Identity Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, adfs2.0

I try to get the role from the user logged from HomeController with ADFS integration, but I´m using .html pages not .cshtml and I need use the claims and the user role in this component pages.

How is the best way to share the current user with angular components?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular, you need [adal.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs).

But this is only available on ADFS 4.0.

You tagged as ADFS 2.0. There is no OAuth support on this version.

Comment: Do you know any tutorial tu use the logging user info in Angular 4?